# Mounting a partition on diffrent windows machine to another linux machine

Tags: linux, mount, linux-networking

I have two different machines one is windows 2003 server and other is linux cent os 5.4.
Both are on the same network. Is there any way that I can mount (network mount) windows 2003 hard drive (NTFS) on to my linux server, so that I will be able to store all my heap-dumps on windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a windows share using the [mount.cifs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) program which is part of the SAMBA suite. You would do something like

`sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mountpoint -o user=remoteusername`

You will be prompted for the password of the remote username. There are ways around this - check the documentation.

Comment: Yes its was like that. just that it was not recognizing cifs file system though. So I mounted it without any option. So command I used is   mount //ip/folder -o username=user, password=password /mnt

Answer (score 0):

It's called SMB (or CIFS). Just make a windows network share, and then have a look a [the documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html) on how to mount it exactly as you want. Should be pretty simple.